# How to solve "@Babel/polyfill is loaded more than once on this page. "?

Tags: reactjs, babel-polyfill

When I enter to my web application/site writen in react 16, I see this error:

```
abel/polyfill is loaded more than once on this page. This is probably not desirable/intended and may have consequences if different versions of the polyfills are applied sequentially. If you do need to load the polyfill more than once, use @babel/polyfill/noConflict instead to bypass the warning.
(
```

[image]

I found someone talk about it here:
https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/2955
But it's specifically for knex package.

Any idea how to solve it? what cause it?

Thanks in advance.